# Is there a missing differential in this integral? $ \int_0^1 \int _0^1 x \cdot \frac 43 \cdot (1-xy) dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The integral is from an example in my probability book. Doesn't a double integral have to have two differentials like below?

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int _0^1 x \cdot \dfrac 43 \cdot (1-xy) dydx?$

The book seems to have evaluated it exactly as if there was a $dx$ too. Here is their calculation:

$\displaystyle \int_0^1 \int _0^1 x \cdot \dfrac 43 \cdot (1-xy) dy = \int_0^1 x \dfrac 43 (1- \dfrac x2) dx = \dfrac 49.$

Comment: Yeah, it looks like they just forgot to include the dx.

Comment: @carmichael561 Hmm ok. I thought it was just a typo as well but then I noticed they did it in another place.

Comment: It should be a typographical error. The value is correct: $\frac{4}{9}$.

Comment: Typos have reproductive systems and propagate.